# How should I implement radio controls using Google Assistant?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, androidx

My use case is the following:
the user is driving or he/she's somehow unable to use his smartphone with his/her hands. All the actions he/she can do are the following:
"hey goole,"

- play playlist $playlistName
- play $radioStation
- play $podcastName of $podcastDate
- pause
- next radio station
- previous radio station

I've seen a Google I/O '18 video where they presented App Actions ([here](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-integrate-actions-in-app-b3787eed283d) a readable version of the presentation). One should basically create an action.xml file where the mapping between the sematic intent and the android intent is created. So, when the user says the "magic words" (semantic intent), the right (android) intent is invoked to fulfill the request.

My questions are:

1. How do I create a semantic intent using the Action Console/Dialogflow console? All I have seen is how to create a conversational app which is not what I need
2. Since on the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions) is stated "Note: Developer preview coming soon!", am I missing something? Is there a way to do what I need using the Actions on Google console?

Note:
To get the Radio contents I use a third-party library

Comment: What do you mean by semantic intent?

Comment: @MaxWiederholt as the article says "These intents describe what your action does in a language that google can understand.". So, for example, the expression "Hey Google, make me a coffee" could be translated into a semantic intent like actions.some.package.MAKE_COFFEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, direct invocation of the Google Assistant ("Hey Google, play Africa by Toto") is not currently available to third party developers.

However, you can use [explicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit) to trigger a Google Assistant action that could then send an HTTP request to a REST API that could communicate with your Android app.

The user can include an invocation phrase at the end of their invocation that will take them directly to the Actions on Google > Dialogflow > Firebase function they're requesting, like so:

[image: Explicit invocation on Google Assistant]

Comment: Ok. So, by using this method, I don't need to implement nothing related to the actions.xml file, am I right?

Comment: I recommend you start with the first codelab for Google Assistant, which covers beginner-level concepts for developing with Actions on Google. You don't need prior experience with the platform to follow along: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0